# Как после 0 ставить запятую в input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

Имеется такой код:

```
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ru");
function handleChange(e){
    var est = e.target.value.toString().replace(/\D/g,'')
    setValue(formatter.format(est));
}
```

При вводе числа в input, он форматирует его в таком виде: 1 000 000
Но мне нужно сделать так, чтоб если пользователь ввёл первым числом 0, то формат был таким: 0,000000
Как это возможно сделать? Весь интернет перекопал, так и не нашел решения этого вопроса. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имеете в виду, допустим как должны конвертироваться эти числа: `0123`, `0,123`, `0.123`?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Например:
`12000` => `12 000`
`0123` => `0,123`
`00123` => `0,0123`
`12,345` => 12,345`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё на самом деле проще чем вы думаете, вот код (снизу его разбор):

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')
let output = document.querySelector('.output')

input.addEventListener('input', handleChange)

// --- Код ответа ---

let formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("ru");

function handleChange(e){
  let target = e.target
  let targetValue = target.value
  let str = targetValue.toString()
  let _str = +(str.replace(/,/, '.'))

  let est = str.replace(/\D/g,'')
  let formatted = formatter.format(est)

  let value

  if(str.startsWith('0')) {
    value = '0,' + str.slice(1)
  } else if(_str && !Number.isInteger(_str)) {
    value = _str.toString().replace(/\./g, ',')
  } else {
    value = formatted
  }

  setValue(value);
}

// --- /Код ответа ---

function setValue(value) {
  output.textContent = value
}
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<p class="output">0</p>
```

Я перенёс некоторые значения в переменные чтобы с ними можно было удобно работать. Объявляем переменную `value`, если наша строка начинается с нуля, тогда `value` будет равнятся `0,` + `value` (но без первого симовола), если же наша строка является `float` (числа с плающей запятой), тогда оставить его как есть, если ни одно из условий не сработало, тогда выдавать сформатированный текст.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Единственное, как можно сделать таким образом, чтоб пользователь мог сам ставить запятую? Условно говоря я ввожу `12,345` и получаю на выходе `12,345` а не `12 345` ?

Comment: @NoNames123 исправил ответ, если вы считаете что мой ответ решил вашу проблему, можете поставить ему галочку (она находится слева от ответа, в верхней части).